# Excerpt added through functions.php - can't remove shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have this code **in my functions.php** (ajax that I used for filtering posts by category), the problem is that I can't remove visual composer shortcodes from the posts excerpt, the excerpt code is

```
<?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post); echo $excerpt; ?>
```

I tried bunch of scripts to remove shortcodes as this one but without results. Any help would be appriciated.

```
function remove_shortcode_from_excerpt($content) {
$content = strip_shortcodes( $content );
return $content;//always return $content
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'remove_shortcode_from_excerpt');
```

---

```
///Ajax post filtering by category
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );
 function prefix_load_cat_posts () { ?>
 <div class="allposts row blogrow">
 <?php ob_start ();
   $query = new WP_Query(
     $args = array (
    'showposts' => 999,
    'cat' => $cat_id = $_POST[ 'cat' ]
    )  );
   $posts = get_posts( $args );
     foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
     setup_postdata( $post );
 ?>

  <div class="functsingnews news-wrap">  
 <div class="newsflex">
 <div class="postfeat"> <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
 <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'my-custom-thumb' ); ?>
 <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">
 <?php endif; ?> 
 </div>
 <div class="postinfo">
 <div class="postcat">
  <?php foreach( (get_the_category($post)) as $category) { ?> 
 <?php echo    $category->cat_name; ?><?php } ?>
 </div>
 <h4 class="newstitle"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h4>
<div class="postexc"><p><?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post); echo $excerpt; ?></p></div>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink; ?>">READ MORE <span     class="rightarrow"></span></a>
 </div>
</div>
</div>


 <?php
} wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
 <div class="next-button"><a href="#" id="loadMoreCat">Load More Posts CAT</a></div>

 <? $response = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

 echo $response;
die(1);
} 

function remove_shortcode_from_excerpt($content) {
$content = strip_shortcodes( $content );
return $content;//always return $content
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'remove_shortcode_from_excerpt');
```

Comment: You have to hook to the wp_trim_excerpt filter, get_the_excerpt filter may return the empty $content

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution, if someone will need this:

```
<?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post); echo $excerpt = preg_replace("~(?:\[/?)[^/\]]+/?\]~s", '', $excerpt);  ?>
```